# Javascript 2D array filled with loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a 2D array javascript using looping, with a result like this:

```
[[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5][b1,b2....]..[...e3,e4,e5]]
```

I have tried multiple different things, using for loops and the below, but am unable to create as needed.

```
var cols = [1,2,3,4,5];
var rows = ["a", "b", "c","d", "e"];

var grid = [ for (r of rows) [ for (c of cols) r+c ] ];
```

any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: initialize an empty array outside the loops say `x`. first loop rows and initialize an empty array inside first loop say 'y'. then loop cols and inside that loop push to y the sum of elements. after the second loop finish push the y to x

Answer (score 4):

You can get your desired result using a nested [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the rows and columns:

```js
var cols = [1,2,3,4,5];
var rows = ["a", "b", "c","d", "e"];

var grid = rows.map(r => cols.map(c => r + c));

console.log(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @Nick beat me to it again ;-) but, obviously, this is the solution:

```js
var cols = [1,2,3,4,5];
var rows = ["a", "b", "c","d", "e"];

const res = rows.map(r=>cols.map(c=>r+c));

console.log(res);
```